# Remove WordPress admin icons or SVG's

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am finding people are choosing Squarespace etc simply because the backend menu is less confusing. I love WordPress and would like to simplify the backend without a plugin.

I am starting by trying to remove icons and SVG's added by plugins. I can remove Woocommerce for example by this code I found

```
add_action("admin_menu", function () {

    foreach ($GLOBALS["menu"] as $position => $tab) {

        if ("woocommerce" === $tab["2"]) {
            $GLOBALS["menu"][$position][6] = "";
            break;
        }

    }


});
```

It's not ideal, and l'd like to use code to remove them in a cleaner fashion, I am aware there are plugins that do it which makes me sure that it can be done programmatically but my experience precludes me from knowing how.

While this works for Woocommerce, I'd like to remove them all as whilst I'm sure at some stage it was trendy or cute it would be nice if it was optional, I know that's a WordPress decision, but for now does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. I hope it helps someone else.
The code provided contains two functions: remove_admin_menu_images and align_admin_menu_text. The first function removes the default admin menu images and color scheme, while the second function adjusts the alignment of the admin menu text.

The styling code within the align_admin_menu_text function is directly embedded in the code itself and does not require an external source.

```
function remove_admin_menu_images() {
remove_action('admin_head', 'wp_admin_css'); // Remove default admin  menu images
remove_action('admin_head', 'wp_admin_css_color'); // Remove default admin menu color scheme
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_images');

function align_admin_menu_text() {
echo '<style>
    #adminmenu .wp-menu-image { display: none !important; } /* Hide menu icons */
    #adminmenu .wp-menu-name { padding-left: 20px !important; } /* Adjust text alignment */
</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'align_admin_menu_text');
```

:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).